# Dictionary<string, string[]> Cannot implicity convert type 'string[]' to 'string'

Tags: c#, arrays, string, dictionary, compiler-errors

I am using a sort of string array collections all in the form of a Dictionary as so ....

Dictionary<(key: topic), (value: string array #File.ReadAllLines(#somepath))>

Example:

```
        public static Dictionary<string, string[]> flags = new Dictionary<string, string[]>()
        {
            { "food", new string[] { l_food }};
        }


        public static string[] l_food = File.ReadAllLine(_path + @"..//..//lists/food.txt");
```

My goal is to use my class:

```
    public class Algorithms
    {
        public static string Main(string message)
        {
            return Get_Response(Get_Topic(message));
        }

        private string Get_Topic(string message)
        {
            string[] words = message.Split(' ');
            foreach (string word in words)
            {
                foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string[]> flag in Responses.flags)
                {
                    if (Responses.ignore.Contains(word) == true) ;
                    else if (flag.Value.ContainsValue(word) == true && Responses.ignore.Contains(word) == false) return flag.Key;
                    else if (flag.Value.ContainsValue(word) == false && word == " " || word == null) return "afk";
                    else return "general";
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

        private string Get_Response(string topic)
        {
            switch (topic)
            {
                case "music":
                    return Set_Response(Responses.r_music);
                case "art":
                    return Set_Response(Responses.r_art);
                case "mathmatics":
                    return Set_Response(Responses.r_mathmatics);
                case "military":
                    return Set_Response(Responses.r_military);
                case "technology":
                    return Set_Response(Responses.r_technology);
                case "science":
                    return Set_Response(Responses.r_science);
                case "religion":
                    return Set_Response(Responses.r_religion);
                case "sex":
                    return Set_Response(Responses.r_sex);
                case "wealth":
                    return Set_Response(Responses.r_wealth);
                case "job":
                    return Set_Response(Reponses.r_job);
                case "games":
                    return Set_Response(Responses.r_games);
                case "food":
                    return Set_Response(Responses.r_food);
                case "politics":
                    return Set_Response(Responses.r_politics);
                case "movie":
                    return Set_Response(Responses.r_movie);
                case "general":
                    return Set_Response(Responses.r_general);
                case "afk":
                    return Set_Response(Responses.r_afk);
                }
            }

            public string Set_Response(string[] topic)
            {
                return topic[(int)new Random().Next(topic.Length)];
            }
        }
```

... to grab the 'topic' (i.e. food) from a user's message by matching possible words that do not get removed by my ignore list from the string array's (loaded from text files).

This is for a chatbot application that I was messing around with but the problem arises when I see this

Error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type `string[]' to`string' (CS0029) (SimpleMan)

Mind you this IDE is MonoDevelop, as my laptop is a crappy 2003 linux box...

I don't really know...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
public static Dictionary<string, string[]> flags = new Dictionary<string, string[]>()
{
    { "food",  l_food };
}
```

`l_food` is a already a `string[]`.